# Getting started with a new iMac

Tags: macos, software-rec, mac

I'm on my first Apple computer, a shiny new 21.5" iMac.

I am not unfamiliar with OS X as I have been using a borrowed MacBook for a few months. Considering that this is my machine, I am more comfortable "settling in".

I would like to get recommendations for software to install on it, other possible uses and whatnot.

***I bought it primarily for iPhone development, but I make videos on my beast of a PC using Adobe Premiere CS3. What software is recommended for me to download for the aforementioned as well as photo editing, graphic design and web design?***

Bear in mind that this machine will NOT have steady internet access and that I'm looking for freeware only.

THANKS!

Comment: The software part is a duplicate of "What are some “must have” Mac OS X programs?" at http://superuser.com/questions/1191/what-are-some-must-have-mac-os-x-programs (EDIT: oh, or maybe not, but the the title needs some work...)

Comment: @Arjan - you are right, a clone, except I'm looking for specific programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As freeware, [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/) has always been useful.

Comment: right, got that one. also have openoffice. xcode. ilife.

Comment: blender and cyberduck are good as well

Answer (score 0):

Well, for video you'll probably want Final Cut Express or Final Cut Studio. As for the other stuff, all of the same stuff you would probably use on Windows... Photoshop, InDesign, Dreamweaver, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Xee is a nice image viewer.